# Grinder: report CPU and Memory data

Tags: performance-testing, grinder

I'd like to have Grinder's agents log CPU and Memory from [OperatingSystemMXBean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html)

Ideally this should create a usual _data.log so I could feed it into [Grinder Analyzer](http://track.sourceforge.net/)

How could I instrument a test to create such a report? Or could I create a test script that would report CPU load values as Test time?

(I read [Best tool to record CPU and memory usage with Grinder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919541/best-tool-to-record-cpu-and-memory-usage-with-grinder))

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919541/best-tool-to-record-cpu-and-memory-usage-with-grinder/44072461#44072461